# JQuery Mobile : 'Back' links not conserving form informations

Tags: jquery, caching, dom, jquery-mobile

So i have this form which is handled with multiple pages called via Ajax.

On the second page, I have a link with the `data-rel="back"` attribute, this links is supposed to redisplay the first page.

With or without `data-dom-cache="true"` to the first page, the page is not cached and clicking this link will fire an Ajax request so all my form data will be lost.

Is there a way to force this page to stay cached and redisplayed when clicking the back button  without too much hacks ?

Comment: Maybe try setting `data-ajax="false"` on the back link?

Comment: @patersonjs nope, same problem !

Comment: Would it be possible to see the code or a simplified example? I imagine the problem is something along the lines of page 1 not being cached (so the back link is forced to request it from the server) - but why, I can only guess. Watch the DOM with Firebug/Inspector when clicking the page 2 link and see if it's actually being loaded via ajax and then inserted into the DOM